# Problem in post http request django restfamework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this ViewSet in my project:

```
class UserCreditCardsViewSet(UserDataModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserCreditCard.objects.none()
    http_method_names = ['post', 'get', 'delete', 'option']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserCreditCard.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    serializers = {
        'default': UserCreditCardsSerializer,
    }
    permission_classes_by_action = {
        'default': [IsAuthenticated],
    }
```

And its the URL routing:

```
router.register(r'accounting/credit_card', UserCreditCardsViewSet,
                basename='UserCreditCard')
```

Everything else working well in my project. But when I want to do a post request to this ViewSet
Its shows this error:

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: From what does `UserDataModelViewSet` inherit ?

Comment: From ModelViewSet

Comment: Which include the `create()` method used on POST... :/ Very strange.
Can you post your curl command too pls ?